# How to set row autoHeight with min height in ag-grid-vue

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I want to set row auto height in ag-grid-vue to adjust multiline content. I am able to achieve it through autoHeight: true for the specific column in column-defs. But it loses min height adjustment of the grid. min height is set using :row-height="50". If I remove autoHeight from column def then min height 50 is working. I also tried setting rowHeight: '50px' in gridOptions but it is not helping.

I want to increase row height based on content when specific column has more content. and for other rows I want to retain min height 50.

```
columnDefs:[{field:'column1', headerName:'Column 1',width:100, autoHeight:true},{field:'column2', headerName:'Column 2',width:100}]

 <ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 500px; height: 200px"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
    :row-height="50"
    :grid-options="gridOptions"
  >
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can use `rowNode.setRowHeight(height)` if you know which row Node will require what height. ref: https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/row-height/#example-row-height-simple

Comment: We already use setRowHeight in grid ready callback to calculate row height dynamically. But it caused some performance issue for 20k+ rows. So I was trying to use autoHeight and also retain min row height.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to set minimum height using below css override. autoHeight is set in columnDef for one column. It adjust row height based on content. and below css apply minimum height for all other rows to 50px instead of 25px (which is ag-grid default)

```
.ag-theme-bootstrap .ag-row {
  min-height: 50px
}
```